# Fast integer power of two

Tags: c++, function

I can't understand these codes for fast integer power of two,

```
inline constexpr std::uint64_t pow2 (std::uint64_t i)
{
    return std::uint64_t(1) << i;
}
```

In fact, I can't understand how following codes work, uint64_t is just a type, int is also OK,

```
return std::uint64_t(1) << i;
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether it is `std::uint64_t(1)` that is confusing you, or the left-shift operator?

Comment: The left-shift operator is confusing me, I feel sorry I haven't clarified my question clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The << is the bit shift operator, which essentially multiplies a number by 2 for every 1 in the number.

so 1<<2 = 1*2*2

3<<5= 3*2*2*2*2*2

And multiplying by 2 for each 1 in the number is just raising 2 to a power and multiplying by the original value. (Thanks for the correction M.M)

Comment: "raising to a power of 2" --> "raising 2 to a power (and multiplying by the original value)

Answer (score 3):

`type(x)` in C++ is simply an alternative to the C type conversion `(type)x`.

So `std::uint64_t(1)` is equivalent to `(std::uint64_t)1` and produces a `std::uint64_t` with value `1`.    (Note: `std::uint64_t` is C++11 or later).

For unsigned integral types, the standard also specifies that left shift `n` is equivalent to multiplying by `2`, `n` times (i.e. multiplying by `2` to the power of `n`), as long as overflow of the type does not occur.

For signed types, the result of left shift is not defined for negative values.

Answer (score 0):

It's just calling the constructor of unit64_t. You don't normally see it used with basic types like that. Normally constructors are used with user defined classes and one might see something like:

```
return A(1);
```

where A is a class defined by the user.

In this case substitute `A` with `std::uint64_t`. Then the `<<` multiplies the value `1` by `2` an `i` number of times.

Comment: Uniform syntax make more sense with templates.

Comment: `uint64_t` does not have a constructor. So it is not good to describe it as "calling the constructor".